# How can I reduce this kind of BinPack algorithm? (It might be called sth like MinBreak-BinFill.)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, np-hard

I use a special variant of BinPack problem.
I use a naïve algorithm, atm, so I like to know **how it might be called** to do some initial research. Or does anyone know **how to reduce this problem** to something known?

---

The problem:
There are items I and bins B in specific quantity and size.

```
|I| ∈ ℕ, |B| ∈ ℕ
s : (I ∪ B) → ℕ
```

The sum of all item-sizes is at least the size of the sum of all bins.

```
∑ _{i∈I} s(i) ≥ ∑ _{b∈B} s(b)
```

Each bin has to be filled with items or parts of items so that it is filled completely. `s(b,i)` is the size of that part of i that is in b, or 0 iff not.

```
∀ b ∈ B, i ∈ I: s(b,i) ∈ ℕ ∪ {0}
∀ i ∈ I: ∑ _{b∈B} s(b,i) ≤ s(i)
∀ b ∈ B: ∑ _{i∈I} s(b,i) ≥ s(b)
```

The goal is to minimize the number of item-parts needed to fill all bins.

```
numparts = |{ (b,i) ∈ B×I | s(b,i)>0 }|
find min(numparts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!

It is called ***bin packing with size preserving fragmentation (BP-SPF)***.

There exists this paper

[**Approximation
Schemes
for
Packing
with
Item
Fragmentation**
*Omer
Yehezkely*](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~hadas/THESES/Omer.pdf)
(November 2006)